# Set hardware flow control to sierra wireless modem wismo228

Tags: controls, hardware, modem

I have a wismo228 modem which i can communicate with using hyperterminal. Currently i set the flow control to none so that this can work.

How can i change the flow control on this modem so i can communicate with it using hardware flow control on hyperterminal?

Thanks.